# Using Rspec should_receive to test that a controller calls a method on an object correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

OK first, I should say while I've read a lot about `should_receive`, I'm still not entirely sure I'm understanding the concept behind it, so what I'm doing could potentially be completely not possible.

I have the following:

```
class PlansController
  def destroy
    plan = plan.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if plan.cancel_stripe_subscription(params[:reason])
      flash[:success] = "success"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      #error handling
    end
  end
end

class Plan
  def cancel_stripe_subscription(reason)
    self.status = "canceled"
    self.cancellation_reason = reason
    if self.save
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

In my controller spec, I am thinking it makes sense to do a test that the `cancel_stripe_subscription` method is called successfully (using 1should_receive1), with the right arguments and everything, and another test that the output of the `destroy` action is correct.

In other words, I thought to write the following controller spec:

```
describe PlansController, "Destroy Action" do
  before do
    @plan = Plan.create(...)
  end
  it "should have called destroy action" do
    delete :destroy,
      plan: {
        id: @plan.id,
        reason: "something"
      }
      assigns(:plan).should_receive(:cancel_stripe_subscription).with(reason:"something").exactly(1).times.and_return(true)
  end

  it "should have called destroy action" do
    delete :destroy,
      plan: {
        id: @plan.id,
        reason: "something"
      }
    assigns(:plan).status.should == "canceled"
    assigns(:plan).cancellation_reason.should == "something"
  end
end
```

The second test passes, but the first throws

```
Failure/Error: assigns(:plan).should_receive(:cancel_stripe_subscription)
   (#<Plan:0x007fe282931310>).cancel_stripe_subscription(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

So I really have two questions:

1. Just to confirm, am I using `should_receive` correctly? Should I even be testing for this? Or is the second test generally accepted as enough?
2. If I should be testing for this, what's the right way of using `should_receive`? (Note, have not had luck with `expect(@plan).to have_received(:cancel_stripe_subscription)` either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `should_receive` expectation has to be set *before* you call the method under test; you're setting it afterwards. Since you need to set it before, you then have to make sure the object you've set up the expectation on ends up being operated on in the action. The normal way would be to stub out `find_by_id` on `Plan`, like this:

```
it "should have called destroy action" do
  Plan.stub(:find_by_id).and_return(@plan)
  assigns(:plan).should_receive(:cancel_stripe_subscription).with(reason:"something").exactly(1).times.and_return(true)
  delete :destroy, plan: { id: @plan.id, reason: "something" }
end
```

(I am assuming that you meant to write `plan = Plan.find_by_id(params[:id])` in the first line of your `destroy` action.)

As to whether you *should* be testing it this way, I'd say that your second test does a good enough job of verifying the outcome that you want, and you don't really need to go to all the trouble.

Comment: OK I think I'm being a little dense here, I'm not entirely sure I understand the difference. Both my way and your way calls the `delete :destroy` first and then checks the `assigns(:plan).should_receive` so that must not be the difference. But you're stubbing a `plan` while I'm using a created `@plan`. Does that mean that one essentially HAS to stub the plan object for `should_receive` to work since otherwise you would have already called the method on the real `@plan` object, therefore making it no longer testable? Am I making sense?

Comment: You are confused because I made a mistake and put the statements in the wrong order. It's fixed now. :)

Comment: OH that is super weird and uncomfortable to me... I'm going to keep my second test =) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion here is in part due to combining two different styles of testing, mockist (your first test) and classicist (your second test). It's fine to use one or the other, based on your preferred testing style, but using both together to test the same piece of code is somewhat redundant.